# Android Studio : Image is Taking spaces but not showing in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code. I have noticed that the code runs without any error. I put  images in list view and the view is taking the spaces of putting the images, but image not showing. It looks like blank (but occupied) spaces.
I am giving here full code so that you can make run to this program.
[Full Code Here](https://github.com/kawshikbuet17/Android-Studio/tree/master/ListView-App/app/src)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `kawshik_layout.xml`, Replace

```
tools:srcCompat="@drawable/keokradong"
```

with

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/keokradong"
```

`Tools` is used only for preview. That's why you are seeing a blank space.

Comment: I have made it by the studio scene builder.  Can it be done from the scene builder? I mean tools>app. Or I must do it from xml code only?

Comment: scene builder will always use `tools`, so you have to replace it will `app` everytime

Comment: Thanks for the information. Glad to know this.